# creating my own library in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.3

I'm trying to create my own library in a Symfony2 project but I'm having a hard time doing so...

Basically I want to reuse an FTP browser class I made for another project.

I copied the class into

```
/vendor/mylib
```

and tried to autoload it like that

```
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
  'Twig_Extensions_' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig-extensions/lib',
  'Twig_'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig/lib',
  'Mylib_'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/mylib'
));
```

I then tried to instantiate a Mylib_Test object inside my bundle's controller and I got this error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test\FrontBundle\Controller\Mylib_Test' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sf2_project/src/Test/FrontBundle/Controller/WelcomeController.php on line 26
```

Anyone has an idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `namespace Test\FrontBundle\Controller;` in your controller. When you call for some class php tries to find it in specified namespace. Mylib_Test is obviously not in that namespace. So you should implicitly indicate that this class should be looked for in global namespace. In order to do that you should prepend class name with backslash:

```
$instance = new \Mylib_Test();
```

More info [in docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)